# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in line chart with json data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get some data in my map, however I have the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
 stroke: steelblue;
 stroke-width: 2;
 fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: grey;
 stroke-width: 1;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute; 
  text-align: center; 
  width: 60px; 
  height: 28px;  
  padding: 2px; 
  font: 12px sans-serif; 
  background: lightsteelblue; 
  border: 0px;     
  border-radius: 8px;
 /*  pointer-events: none; This line needs to be removed */
 
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var w = window.innerWidth,
          h = window.innerHeight,
        margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
 width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
var formatTime = d3.time.format("%e %B");// Format tooltip date / time




  // We're passing in a function in d3.max to tell it what we're maxing (x value)
      var x = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.x + 10; })])
          .range([margin.left, w - margin.right]);  // Set margins for x specific

      // We're passing in a function in d3.max to tell it what we're maxing (y value)
      var y = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.y + 10; })])
          .range([margin.top, h - margin.bottom]);  // Set margins for y specific

      // Add a X and Y Axis (Note: orient means the direction that ticks go, not position)
      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(5);
      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(5);







// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
 .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

// Define 'div' for tooltips
var div = d3.select("body")
 .append("div")  // declare the tooltip div 
 .attr("class", "tooltip")              // apply the 'tooltip' class
 .style("opacity", 0);                  // set the opacity to nil

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
  .attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data


var datajson = '[        { x: 100, y: 110 },        { x: 83, y: 43 },        { x: 92, y: 28 },        { x: 49, y: 74 },        { x: 51, y: 10 },        { x: 25, y: 98 },        { x: 77, y: 30 },        { x: 20, y: 83 },        { x: 11, y: 63 },        { x:  4, y: 55 },        { x:  0, y:  0 },        { x: 85, y: 100 },        { x: 60, y: 40 },        { x: 70, y: 80 },        { x: 10, y: 20 },        { x: 40, y: 50 },        { x: 25, y: 31 }      ]';


var data = JSON.parse(datajson); 



 data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.x = d.x;
  d.y = +d.y;
 });


 // Add the valueline path.
 svg.append("path")  
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline(data));

 // draw the scatterplot
 svg.selectAll("dot")         
  .data(data)           
 .enter().append("circle")        
  .attr("r", 5) 
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })   
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
 // Tooltip stuff after this
     .on("mouseover", function(d) {  
            div.transition()
    .duration(500) 
    .style("opacity", 0);
   div.transition()
    .duration(200) 
    .style("opacity", .9); 
   div .html(
    '<a href= "http://google.com">' + // The first <a> tag
    d.x +
    "</a>" +                          // closing </a> tag
    "<br/>"  + d.y)  
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")    
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
   });

 // Add the X Axis
 svg.append("g") 
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

 // Add the Y Axis
 svg.append("g") 
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);



</script>
</body>
```

It goes wrong at line 59:

```
  var y = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.y + 10; })])
```

I am trying to plot line chart with points.

Comment: Please make sure your example is a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your JSON string should be like:

```
    var datajson = '[        { "x": 100, "y": 110 },        
{ "x": 83, "y": 43 },        { "x": 92, "y": 28 },        
{ "x": 49, "y": 74 },        
{ "x": 51, "y": 10 },        { "x": 25, "y": 98 },
{ "x": 77, "y": 30 },        { "x": 20, "y": 83 },
{ "x": 11, "y": 63 },        { "x":  4, "y": 55 },
{ "x":  0, "y":  0 },        { "x": 85, "y": 100 },
{ "x": 60, "y": 40 },        { "x": 70, "y": 80 },
{ "x": 10, "y": 0 },        { "x": 40, "y": 50 },
{ "x": 25, "y": 31 }      ]';
```

Note the double codes(") on the key.

Next

You are setting the domain like:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.x + 10;
      })])
      .range([margin.left, w - margin.right]); //
```

But data is defined much below this line.

So please move the below lines above:

```
var data = JSON.parse(datajson);



    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.x = d.x;
      d.y = +d.y;
    });
```

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/KmWVYMR9vDMRSmBGFjok?p=preview)